# Image of the trace map for a $2\times 2$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I want to find the base for the image and kernel for the trace map. Specifically for a $2\times 2$ Matrix. I have an idea for the kernel but I'm not quite sure about the image.

Let $A \in Mat_2(\mathbb{R})$ then the trace map is defined as $Mat_2(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}; A \rightarrow tr(A)$

How would I go about finding the base for the image? Is it just a real number (i.e. base = {t*1}) or is that insufficient?

Comment: The image is all of $\bf R$, so a basis is given by $\{\,1\,\}$.

Comment: The correct word is "basis," not "base."